# What is the fastest way to record the listed files in a directory in C?

Tags: c, file-system

I want to fill an array of `dirent` pointers with each entry of a specified directory. I either need to count the items before, allocate memory, then go over them again, or I will have to reallocate each iteration of the while loop. Both of these options seem slow. Surely there's a better way.

Are these my only option:

```
struct dirent **Entries;
DIR *Dir = opendir("Some dir path");
struct dirent *Entry;
unsigned int Count = 0;
while ((Entry = readdir(Dir))) {
    Count++;
}
Entries = malloc(Count*sizeof(struct dirent*));
rewinddir(Dir);
for (int i = 0; (Entry = readdir(Dir); i++) {
    Entries[i] = Entry;
}
```

Or

```
struct dirent **Entries;
DIR *Dir = opendir("Some dir path");
Dir = opendir("Some dir path");
struct dirent *Entry;
for (int i = 0; (Entry = readdir(Dir); i++) {
    Entries = realloc(Entries, i*sizeof(struct dirent*));
    Entries[i] = Entry;
}
closedir(Dir);
```

Or is there some faster way?

Comment: C and the standard C library have no ways to read a directory.  Fastest way is implementation dependent - if it exists.  I recommend to add a tag to the implementation used.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But surely there's a cross platform way?

Comment: Not in general.  Again, recommend to add a tag to the implementation used.  Not all platforms have a file system.

Comment: Curious, why `char*` in `malloc(Count*sizeof(char*));`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I made a boo boo. I MADE A BOO BOO!

Comment: We could provide better suggestions if you included more of the code rather than just snippets.

Comment: Please do not edit the code after an answer has been posted. The code that everyone sees should be the same.

Comment: I decided to use [`scandir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir) for this purpose.

Comment: @pacmaninbw That was a boo boo and none of the answers rely on it.

Comment: It was observed by the person that wrote the review, and the rules are clear that code should not be edited after an answer has been posted.

Comment: @user226181 Use `Entries = malloc(Count*sizeof *Entries);` and 1) not make boo boos, easier to review and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP poses 2 approaches

1. Iterate twice through `opendir(), readdir(), closedir()` with one `malloc()`.
2. Iterate one through `opendir(), readdir(), closedir()` with multiple `realloc()`.

For performance, I would use a 3rd option: linked list instead of using an array of `struct dirent`

3. Iterate once through `opendir(), readdir(), closedir()` with one `malloc()` per entry.

---

As with such performance issue: strive for reduced [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), not linear ones.

Comment: I like how you understand my question. You put my problems in better words than I did :)